# Replace observation number with another

Tags: sas

I am a total SAS-noobie. I hope you can help me out with this question. 
I have a data set with 159 observations. All observations have an id number (variable=id). Number 68 is missing. I would like to change id=160 to id=68, so the number of observations fits with the id numbers. Does anyone know how to do this?
My data set looks something like this:

```
    obs:  id:
    ...   ...
    67    67
    68    69
    69    70
    ...   ...
    159   160
```

So to elaborate I would like to change the row obs=159, id=160 to row obs=68, id=68.

I tried:

if obs=159 then id=68;

This didnt help :-/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please elaborate your question --So Reviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope I understand correctly what you try to accomplish: "changing a value in column **id**"

See example:

```
DATA survey; 
INPUT id sex $ age inc r1 r2 r3 ; 
DATALINES; 
1  F  35 17  7 2 2 
81  M  44 11  7 7 7 
2   F  34 17  6 5 3 
18  M  40 14  7 5 2 
34  F  47  6  6 5 6 
160  M  35 17  5 7 5 
;

proc print data=survey; *print the dataset survey created as you can     see that 160 is in original dataset;

data recode;
set survey;
if id=160 then id=68;
run;

PROC SORT DATA=recode OUT=surveysorted ; *sort the data;
BY id ;
RUN ;

PROC PRINT DATA=surveysorted ; *print new sorted dataset;
RUN ;
```

output: [image: **output for proc print data=survey; and proc print DATA=surveysorted;**]

Comment: Okay, it works! I tried the same earlier but couldn't make it work. I must have typed wrong in some way. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the value based on the observation's order in the table than you should type:

```
 if _N_=159 then id=68;
```

This works only in a data step.

hope this helps

MK